# Postgres Group/compress result row inside 1 linked row

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a table structure with 2 table like this:

**result** table: 1 Row with generic into + a row UUID.

```
--------------------------
| uuid    | name | other |
--------------------------
| result1 | foo  | bar   |
--------------------------
| result2 | foo2 | bar2  |
--------------------------
```

**criteria_result**:

```
-----------------------------------
| result_uuid | crit_uuid | value |
-----------------------------------
| result1     | crit1     | 7     |
-----------------------------------
| result1     | crit2     | 8     |
-----------------------------------
| result1     | crit3     | 9     |
-----------------------------------
| result1     | crit7     | 4     |
-----------------------------------
| result2     | crit1     | 2     |
-----------------------------------
```

What I need is 1 row per **result** table but that group all the **criteria_result** table inside, ex:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| uuid    | name |         result_crit              |
----------------------------------------------------
| result1 | foo  | [                              
                 |   | crit1 | crit2 | crit3 | crit7 |
                 |   | 7     | 8     | 9     | 4     |]
----------------------------------------------------
| result2 | foo2  | [                              
                  |   | crit1 |
                  |   |  2    | ]
----------------------------------------------------
```

Or even

```
-----------------------------------------
| uuid    | name |      result_crit     |
-----------------------------------------
| result1 | foo  | [ | name  | value |
                     | crit1 |  7    |
                     | crit2 |  8    |
                     | crit3 |  9    |
                     | crit7 |  4    |  ]
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
| result2 | foo2  | [ | name  | value |
                      | crit1 |  2    |  ]
-----------------------------------------
```

Anything that can get only 1 result per row when I export it but also have all Criteria of that row/result in a sub array/object.

```
SELECT 
  result.uuid, 
  result.name, 
  criteria_result.result_uuid
FROM 
  public.criteria_result, 
  public.result
WHERE 
  result.uuid = criteria_result.result_uuid;
```

I tried CUBE, GROUP BY, GROUPING SETS, but I don't seems to get it right or find the answer :/.
Thanks
Note: I do have a recent Postgres 9.5.1.

Comment: `select result.uuid, result.name, array_agg(criteria_result.crit_uuid), array_agg(criteria_result.value)
from public.criteria_result join public.result on (result.uuid = criteria_result.result_uuid)
group by result.uuid, result.name;`

Comment: Thanks, That is the function I needed: "array_agg"